# Finding nontrivial solutions to a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I have two equations for real numbers
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2=1
$$
$$
af-be+cd=0
$$
I would like to find a solution $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ such that none of its entries are zero and all entries are distinct, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: :do you want  Find one nontrivial solutions fr this system?

Comment: yes, any solution will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two equations in six unknowns, you should be able to pick four of them and solve for the other two.  Because of the sum of squares, the numbers need to be small, in particular less than 1 in absolute value.  It is easier if you are solving for two variables that aren't multiplied  together in the second equation, so let us imagine we will solve for $a$ and $b$.  Then let $c^2+d^2+e^2+f^2=g, cd=h$, both of which will be known when we pick the four variables.  Now the equations are $$a^2+b^2=1-g \\ af-be=-h$$ which we can solve by substitution.  $$a=\frac{be-h}f\\ \frac {(be-h)^2}{f^2}+b^2=1-g\\(e^2+f^2)b^2-2ehb+h^2+gf^2-f^2=0$$ which is a quadratic we can solve by the usual formula.  I just took $c=0.1,d=0.2,e=0.3,f=0.4$ and found $a \approx 0.469422, b\approx 0.692563$ and $a \approx -0.53342, b\approx -0.64456$ as solutions.

Answer (score 2):

By adding (subtracting) twice the second equation to (from) the first, your system is **equivalent** to \begin{eqnarray*}(a+f)^2+(b-e)^2+(c+d)^2&=&1,\\
(a-f)^2+(b+e)^2+(c-d)^2&=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $(a\pm f,b\mp e,c\pm d)$ can be thought of as points on the unit 2-sphere, and so can be parametrized by 
\begin{eqnarray*}(a+f,b-e,c+d)&=&(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\cos\phi),\\
(a-f,b+e,c-d)&=&(\cos\theta',\sin\theta'\sin\phi',\sin\theta'\cos\phi').
\end{eqnarray*}
This yields $a=(\cos\theta+\cos\theta')/2$ etc, giving a representation of the 4-parameter ($\theta,\theta',\phi,\phi')$ solution. Pick a value for each parameter to get a particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

From your equetions one has $(a+f)^2+(b-e)^2+(c+d)^2=1$.

If you want to get *some* solution, set, for example, $a+f=c+d=2(b-e)$, then one has $b-e=\pm 1/3$  etc.

Comment: This wont guarantee that both the equations are satisfied. One has to check explicitly whether these solutions satisfy both the equations.

Comment: @Abhra Abir Kundu : It's enough to satisfy only the second equation, and this is not difficult.

Comment: @Abhra Abir Kundu :  Here another question arises: is there a rational solution? I tried to find it, but didn't.